# How long does it take to read the Sutta Pitaka (exluding the Kuddhaka Nikaya)?

Tags: pali-canon, tipitaka, study

I bought the Digha Nikaya, Majjhima Nikaya, Samyutta Nikaya and Anguttara Nikaya from Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi's translations and was wondering how long it will take to read through these 4 Pitakas?

I once read that it takes approx 2 years to read through the entire Sutta Pitaka (I don't have the 5th Pitaka the Kuddhaka Nikaya). Is that correct?

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

If you read daily for at least an hour a day, you should finish much sooner than in two years. I have read them on my daily commute to work and it took me about 6 months, but I must admit I skipped Digha and did not finish all of the Anguttara, so if we add that I guess it will come up to about a year...?

It really depends on your reading speed though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I consider myself fairly good at reading English and think that 1 year sounds reasonable. I also don't want to read through them too fast but in a pace that allows me to ponder what's being written. My plan is actually to read for 1 hour a day. In the weekend maybe 2 hours:) I wish the venerable some day would also translate the Kuddhaka Nikaya:)

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy reading the English translations of suttas. It’s so much fun that I don’t mind how time goes into it. I have been reading for almost four years now but haven’t finished it yet. Every sutta is complete in itself. I revisit it again and again if something strikes me.You were much faster. It takes time understand and once you understand realisation comes. So take your time, mine was 4 years and counting.

Comment: Thank you very much Dheeraj:) I want to take my time reading them so I can also understand them.